# Команда отправления сообщений пользователям

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Идея такая:
При написании `/send 123 text` чтобы была отправка сообщения (`text`) по айди `123`.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так.

```
from aiogram.utils.exceptions import MessageTextIsEmpty

@dp.message_handler(commands=['send'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user_id, *text = message.get_args().split()
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=" ".join(text))
    except MessageTextIsEmpty:
        await message.answer("Вы не написали текст сообщения")
```

Comment: иногда выводит ошибку ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) из-за того что я пишу два слова или больше, /send 123 да да и сразу эта ошибка...

Comment: Теперь должно быть нормально